# For Python 3.5, can a subclass be constructed from an alternate constructor of its superclass?

Tags: python, inheritance, python-3.5, multiple-constructors

This is a corner I have painted myself into a few times. I would have thought given how common alternate constructors are in Python that it would not be unheard of to construct a subclass from an alternate constructor of its superclass, but I can't think of how to do that or find a discussion about it online.

To illustrate the problem. Say I have the following toy superclass.

```
class Parent:

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0

    @classmethod
    def from_x(cls, x):
        a = cls()
        a.x = x
        return a
```

Now say that I want to subclass `Parent` using its `from_x` method. I can think of four unsatisfying solutions.

1. Calling the superclass's alternate constructor in the subclass's `__init__` as shown below fails because `from_x` does not modify its input like `__init__` but returns a value more like `__new__`.

   ```
   # failed solution

   class Child(Parent):

       def __init__(self):
           super().from_x(1)
   ```
2. Calling the superclass's `from_x` method in the subclass's `__new__` as shown below also fails because both methods call each other circularly.

   ```
   # failed solution

   class Child(Parent):

       def __new__(self):
           return super().from_x(1)
   ```
3. Overriding the superclass's `from_x` method in the subclass makes the subclass's important `__init__` method vestigial and makes it assign the wrong value to x.

   ```
   # bad solution

   class Child(Parent):

       @classmethod
       def from_x(cls):
           return super().from_x(1)
   ```
4. Giving up on inheritance and using composition instead works, but adds an unhelpful layer of syntax (i. e. `child.parent.x`).

   ```
   # unfortunate compromise solution            

   class Child:

       def __init__(self):
           self.parent = Parent.from_x(3)
   ```

Did I miss a better option for this goal?

Comment: If it helps, you can change the class of an instance by setting the `__class__` property.  I can't seem to get it to work right in this case, but I think that your `from_x` method should be able to create a parent and then set `a.__class__` to `cls` before returning it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, thank you for the link to the duplicate question. I was unable to find that myself. Your answer there offers the equivalent of my third solution to this problem, which disappoints me because it makes the subclass's important `__init__` method, at best, secondary to `from_x` and, at worst, a practically guaranteed error that complicates duck-typing that equivocates between the superclass and subclass. @Mathew, thank you for your suggestion. I also understand your suggestion as going with my third solution. That seems like the concensus on this issue. Thanks.

Comment: @Matthew, I figured out how to apply your suggestion to get an instance of the superclass then change its `__class__` property to the subclass. It actually works with my second solution above when `super()` is explicitly replaced by the superclass. I submitted this whole solution as an answer to the question that mine duplicates. Thank you again for the suggestion.

Comment: You did basically what I had intended.  I actually had the child new method calling `super.from_x(1)` and had the parent from_x method doing `a = Parent()` and finishing with `a.__class__ = cls` before returning.  You are just changing the class on the child instead of the parent like I did.  You figured out what was messing me up, though.  I hadn't thought of passing in the child init method.  My child kept having the x value as 0.  It wasn't striking me that the init method was resetting it after it was created.

Comment: Could you replace the toy with something more representative of your *actual* situation? You're having this trouble because what you're doing is a bit weird; a sensible alternate constructor class method ends with `return cls(...)`.